# Ask questions on GitHub without raising an issue

Tags: github-pages, github-issues

It’s happened to many I’m sure: you're on GitHub trying to install some new software, and it’s just not working right. It might be the software, or it might be that you didn't understand something, or something went wrong along the way. As in, your issue may not be an issue of the project you are trying to install.

Is there a way to ask general questions on GitHub, about any project, without raising an issue for the entire project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on StackOverflow is the place to ask your questions about a certain project without raising an issue for the entire project. Remember to tag all your questions as "Git" or "GitHub" I give you direct link hope this is helpful

- https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I was referred to this site by someone on Stack overflow chat. so...

Comment: It depends on the project size, though; for smaller projects, it's often more helpful to just try to contact the author directly (e.g. via Twitter or e-mail, if available)